# @PreUpdate on One of OneToMany?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

When updating the underlying list of a OneToMany relationship is there a way to get a @PreUpdate trigger on the One side?

```
one.getManyList().add(many);
```

triggers @PreUpdate on `many's` class, but nothing on `one's`. This probably makes sense from a db point of view as only `many's` table is affected, but I *really* need the trigger to fire on `one's` class.

Any way to make this happen? Using EclipseLink FWIW.

TIA.

---

So far the best I've come-up with is a `@PreUpdate` in `Many` which sets a `many` specific timestamp in `one` which *in turn* triggers `@PostUpdate` in `One`.

Not exactly optimal but it does give me a single event in `One` regardless of the number of `manys` that are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Many specific timestamp in the One updated from @PreUpdate in the Many is the most efficient solution.

Multiple Many-side @PreUpdates can fire and only one One-side @PostUpdate is triggered.